# How can you select an HTML element associated only with a specific class

Tags: jquery, css, class

I have the following 3 elements in HTML:

```
<span class="a b"></span>
<span class="a"></span>
<span class="a b"></span>
```

I want to select the element which has only class "a".
If I simply do `$("span.a")`, then all three elements will be selected.
Additionally, I want to do it in a for loop because based on this I have to do some other calculation.

It looks like a simple issue but for some reason I am not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different approach than @dfsq

```
$('.a:not(.b)')
```

Select everything with class `a` that does not have class `b`.  This also works in plain CSS selectors.

```
.a:not(.b) {
    color: red;
}
```

If you want "exactly `.a` and nothing else" then dfsq's solution is great. If you want more flexibility with combinations of classes then this may work better.

This snippet demonstrates it:

```css
.a:not(.b) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="a b">This span has class="a b"</span><br>
<span class="a">This one has only class="a"</span><br>
<span class="a b">This also has class="a b"</span><br>
```

Answer (score 5):

Select element by `class` attribute:

```
$("span[class='a']")
```

Comment: This is one of the rare occasions when you would want to literally check the class attribute instead of using the class selector.

Comment: Depending on what the OP intends to do with the for-loop, the OP could incorporate `each()`: `$("span[class='a']").each(function(){ $(this).attr('class'); //a });`